# inyect activity in viewmodel [Dagger/MissingBinding] android.app.Activity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I was developing an App where I'm usng Hilt to make some dependecy inyection, as MainActivity instance which I need in my hiltViewModel

here is my implemenetation of di layer:

AppModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {
    private val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()

    //If it needed add interceptor in the instance of httpClient above.

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideSharedPreferences(@ApplicationContext context: Context) =
        context.getSharedPreferences(
            "shared_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCodigoQRODeBarrasApi(): CodigoQRODeBarrasApi {
    return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(CodigoQRODeBarrasApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFirmaApi(): FirmaApi {
        return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(FirmaApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideImpresoraApi(): ImpresoraApi {
        return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(ImpresoraApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLecturaDeTarjetasApi(): LecturaDeTarjetasApi {
        return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(LecturaDeTarjetasApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMiFareApi(): MiFareApi {
        return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(MiFareApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providePINPADApi(): PINPADApi {
        return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(PINPADApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideTransaccinApi(): TransaccinApi {
        return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(TransaccinApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

AppActivityModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
internal abstract class AppActivityModule {

    @Module
    @InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
    internal interface MainActivityModule {
        @Binds
        fun bindMainActivity(activity: MainActivity) : Activity
    }
}
```

AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AppModule::class,
    AppActivityModule::class,
    AppActivityModule.MainActivityModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): AppComponent
        @BindsInstance
        fun inject(application: Application): Builder
    }
}
```

Regarding my MainActivyt and HiltViewModel implementation is the following:

MainActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HioPosConnectorTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
                //Put here because we need access to Compose context to manage SharePreferences.
                //interpreter = IntentInterpreter(this, intent, LocalContext.current.getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE))
                //interpreter.launchProcess()
                viewModel = hiltViewModel()
                //viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MainViewModel::class.java] // This force to call init() in MainViewModel
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(activity: Activity, sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences) :ViewModel() {
    private val request = HioPosRequest.forIntent(activity.intent, activity)

    init {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){

some code ...

... }
```

The detailed error which i'm getting is this:

```
MyApplication_HiltComponents.java:128: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] android.app.Activity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements FragmentGetContextFix.FragmentGetContextFixEntryPoint,
                         ^
      android.app.Activity is injected at
          es.paytef.hioposconnector.MainViewModel(activity, �)
      es.paytef.hioposconnector.MainViewModel is injected at
          es.paytef.hioposconnector.MainViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [es.paytef.hioposconnector.MyApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? es.paytef.hioposconnector.MyApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? es.paytef.hioposconnector.MyApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

So I try to annotate with @Provide the bindMainActivity method but get into another error.

What am I missing here?

Thank in advance!